# itms-services link intermitently "cannot connect to server"

Tags: ios, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, enterprise-distribution

I'm currently developing an enterprise distribution platform for iOS apps. 
Im storing my files on AWS S3 and generating a signed URL to the plist and ipa. Everything works except intermitently i get an error of "cannot connect to bucketname.s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com". This error occurs about 1 in four times.

I'm using boto to generate the signed urls and when i test the urls in the browser that are used when i get the error they work perfectly fine.

Could this be an AWS issue?

Any ideas are appreciated.

Comment: Hi. How often (per seconds) do you send requests? Maybe server has a limit of requests per second.

Comment: im running of a development server on my own computer, im only sending maybe max 2 per minute, shouldnt be a problem handling this id of thought

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My Problem was that Boto was creating signed URLs with %2B in the signature these needed to be encoded to %252B.